# How to create a string on the prototype of a class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

When I create a class with a string field, it always transpiles into an assignment in the constructor. Is it possible to make it be on the prototype so that it's shared instead of a new string per instance?

```
class A { 
    a = 'hello'
    b() { return this.a;}
}
// Transpiles into
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.a = 'hello';
    }
    A.prototype.b = function () { return this.a; };
    return A;
}());
// Is it possible to make it go on the prototype like functions do?
// No need for multiple instances of the string
var A = (function () {
    function A() {}
    A.prototype.b = function () { return this.a; };
    A.prototype.a = 'hello';
    return A;
}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and it's probably more straight forward that you imagined...

```
class A {
  public foo: string;
}
A.prototype.foo = 'im shared between instances';
```

If you are interested in the reasoning why there is no special to keyword to define a 'prototype member' inside the class definition, you can read more about it [here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/444777). Look for the comment from ahejlsberg (Anders Hejlsberg).

You can also make the variable static, in which case it would be stored on the constructor function\class.

Comment: I do want it to be inherited in my case (not static)... Yes, this is what I was looking for!